# Possible threading issue with pyodbc

Tags: python, oracle, python-2.7, pyodbc

I have an existing system where an oracle database is populated with metadata by a series of Python files. There are around 500, and the current method of running them one at a time is taking around an hour to complete.

To cut down on this runtime, I've tried threading the individual files, running them in concurrently, but I've been getting a the error

```
pyodbc.IntegrityError: ('23000', '[23000] [Oracle][ODBC][Ora]ORA-00001: unique constraint (DB.PK_TABLE_NAME) violated\n (1) (SQLExecDirectW)')
```

with a traceback to the following call:

```
File "C:\file.py", line 295, in ExecuteSql
cursor.execute(Sql)
```

Can anyone shed any light on this for me by any chance? This doesn't seem to be happening if a file which has thrown the error is then run individually, which leads me to suspect this is an access issue where two files are trying to write to the DB at once. I hope this is not the case, as that will likely veto this approach entirely.

Comment: You seem to be running into a identifier collision. Are your INSERTs wrapped in transactions? Are you sharing a single connection or cursor across the multiple threads?

Comment: @FlipperPA Each of the threads has its own connection. They're not wrapped in transactions (its a very hacked-together approach that I'm trying to improve bit by bit)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I eventually realised that the issue was coming from the way that the SQL submitted to the database was being constructed.

The ID for the table was being generated by a "GetNext()" function, which got the current max ID from the table and incremented it by one. This was failing when multiple files were being run - and trying to use the same ID based on this generated - at the same time.